# Why do I get a parsing error parse error when I parse XML

Tags: python, parsing, xml-parsing, elementtree, traceback

I'm trying to parse an XML code with Element tree but when I try to parse it this shows up

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
```

The line that gives me Traceback is

```
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
```

Could any one tell me why this is not working and what is the "invalid token"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is `data`? Please provide a [mcve]. There are several old questions about the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError%3A+not+well-formed%22+is%3Aquestion

Comment: You are in a much better position than we are to see what is at position 0 in `data`. You might have to do a bit of work, like using a debugger or just printing out the characters (preferably in hex, since unprintable characters will trigger an XML parsing error). But those of use who do not have access to advanced NSA surveillance technology have absolutely no way to see what's inside a variable in your machine, unless you tell us.

Comment: Thank you all, Im new at this so thankyou for helping and I already found out what the problem is